# If a cells are selected (from more than one sheet) then show message box

Tags: vba, excel

For starters, I am self taught and still learning (I learn a great deal from this website). That being said, please do not assume something is obvious. I will need help altering the code if your solution is too complex.

What I want to accomplish is; if you select cell A10 on "Sheet3", "Sheet4", and "Sheet5" then I want a message box to appear with the information from Sheets("Sheet6").Range("A1").

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A10")) Is Nothing Then ' this range is where you click to get the msgbox
                Dim rng As Range, s As String, x As String
                Set rng = Sheets("Sheet6").Range("A1") ' this defines x
                 s = "Define: " ' s is what appears first
                 x = s & rng.Value ' x is what appears after s

                 MsgBox x
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

What I would like to happen; if you are in "Sheet3", "Sheet4", and "Sheet5" and select A10 in any of those three sheets, it will appear with the message box that is defined in the code.

What is working; currently this is a private sub that is directly in "Sheet5". When it is here, if cell A10 (in "Sheet5") is selected the information from "Sheet6" A1 appears in the message box as I want.

What is not working; because this is a private sub and is inside "Sheet5" I am struggling to get it to work with A10 from "Sheet3" and "Sheet4".

I attempted to alter the code by moving it and declaring it a public sub to work for all sheets but so far am unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worksheet_SelectionChange has to be in the private module of a worksheet. However it can then call another routine in a public module

So if you put

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   CheckSelection target
End Sub
```

Into each of your three sheets, you can then put your code in a public module

```
    Public Sub CheckSelection(Target as range)
        etc
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully. I will accept the answer as soon as it will allow me to.

Answer (score 2):

For a different approach, this only needs to be entered once, inside the `ThisWorkbook` object.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Select Case Sh.Name

        Case Is = "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5"

            If Target.Address = "$A$10" Then

                    MsgBox Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("A1").Value

            End If

    End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a fun project! To expand a little more on the answer, when you use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event, this is an event that happens to a specific object. That's why it only works for the one sheet that has the code behind it. To have this work in multiple sheets, you could take one of the three following approaches.

**Option 1**: Copy the code to each worksheet object. This is the simplest approach, in one sense, but it can be messy to maintain copies of the same code in multiple locations.

**Option 2**: Put your code in a public function in a standard module. This way you can maintain your code routine in one location, and use the minimal necessary code to call this from each worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    MySpecialFunction Target
End Sub
```

For most cases, you will probably find this to be the most efficient way to handle the need.

**Option 3**: Another more advanced way to do this is to use a wrapper class object. This allows you to dynamically apply your function to any active sheet, without having to add the (option 2) code to each worksheet. While this is more complex, it allows you to apply your event-driven code to any worksheet, even new ones created by your users.

To do this, create a Class Module in your project, and name it `clsMyClass`. Then paste in the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents MySheet As Worksheet

Private Sub MySheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Do neat stuff here...
End Sub
```

The key thing here is that `WithEvents` declaration. This is what allows you to tap into an ***event*** from an object variable. (But you can only do this from a class object, not a standard module.)

Then in your `Workbook_Open()` event, or somewhere else in your project, you can add the function that adds all current worksheets to a collection, allowing you to harness the `SelectionChange` event for all of these worksheets *without needing to add code to each one.*

```
Option Explicit

Private mcolSheets As Collection

Public Sub ActivateCodeForAllWorksheets()

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim cSheet As clsMyClass

    ' Initialize module-level collection
    Set mcolSheets = New Collection

    For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Create new instance of class
        Set cSheet = New clsMyClass
        ' Set to the current worksheet in our loop,
        ' and add to the collection so the sheet object
        ' reference perists after this sub finishes.
        Set cSheet.MySheet = wks
        mcolSheets.Add cSheet
    Next wks

End Sub
```

In real life this can be very useful for things like applying special formatting to a text box when it has the focus, and having this behavior consistent across a large number of objects without needing hundreds of lines of repeated code.

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: Wow, this is very interesting. It is a bit out of my capabilities currently but I just ordered a few books to expand my VBA knowledge as I am completely unfamiliar with wrapper class objects. Thank you for this! I am going to save this to my desktop for later! :)